# how to clear tokenfield with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-tokenfield

I want to make a reset button for a jquery tokenfield, but dont know how to reset it.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="testtokenfield" id="testtokenfield" placeholder="testtokenfield" value="">
<button onclick ="clear()"></button>
```

JS

```
$('#testtokenfield').tokenfield({
        showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
}); 
function clear(){
     document.getElementById('testtokenfield').value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
$('#testtokenfield').tokenfield('destroy');
```

Reference: [Tokenfield for Bootstrap](https://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#methods).

Comment: This will distroy the entire tokenField input and will turn it into simple input ,

Answer (score 0):

Use [setToken](https://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#methods) method to pass empty array to your input

```
$('#testtokenfield').tokenfield('setTokens', []);
```

see below working snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#testtokenfield').tokenfield({
    autocomplete: {
      source: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'violet', 'brown', 'purple', 'black', 'white'],
      delay: 100
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
  });

 $("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
 
  $('#testtokenfield').tokenfield('setTokens', []);
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/docs-assets/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
<script src="http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/css/tokenfield-typeahead.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<input type="text" class="input" name="testtokenfield" id="testtokenfield" placeholder="" value="">
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btn">clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="testtokenfield" id="testtokenfield" placeholder="testtokenfield"/>
<button id='clearbtn'>Clear</button>
    
const testtokenfield= document.getElementById("testtokenfield");        
const clearbtn= document.getElementById("clearbtn");

clearbtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                // clearing the input field
                testtokenfield.value = " ";
            })
```

> we need to attach a click event to the clear button element and set a testtokenfield.value property to an empty string " ". so that when a user clicks on the button, the input field value is cleared.